# Call Method in ApplicationController from Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a Gem that handles authentication of users via a third party, and want to sign in a specific user using Devise, through a method in the Application Controller.

I need to pass information about which user has been authenticated from the gem to the main app.

When I try calling ApplicationControllers's
completed_authentication_sign_in(@user) method in the Gem, I get this error:

**NoMethodError (undefined method `completed_authentication_sign_in' for #<*GemName*::*ClassName*:0x000055ab8839ef70>):**

*application_controller.rb*

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  def completed_authentication_sign_in(user)
    @user = user
    sign_in_and_redirect(@user)
  end
  ...
end
```

*custom_gem.rb*

```
module GemName
  class ClassName
    ... # authenticates and sets the @user object.
    completed_authentication_sign_in(@user)
  end
end
```

I've tried calling Device's sign_in_and_redirect(@user) method directly in the Gem, but that doesn't work as it's missing relevant session information.

Comment: Controller methods run in the context of a request. That means they handle user input or simple GET requests and return data, for example, an HTML page, JSON, or a redirect to the browser. How does your gem work? Will it be called from a controller? How?

Comment: Have you included the gem? Or used the Gem's namespace in the invocation?

Comment: The gem is called through a URL callback (app.com/users/auth/callback), that then triggers the method in the ClassName in the gem (authenticates the user), and I'd then like to call the method in ApplicationController with the authenticated user as a parameter, to then sign them in. @spickermann

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery Yes, I tried that in the Gem, including the Device gem into it when I tried calling the sign_in method directly from the gem, but it was still missing the session data (later confirmed that Device only supports the method being called from a Controller)